# Get Simple Item Information on Order Success Page

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get simple product data on Magento Order Success Page. I have the following code:

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($orderId, 'increment_id');
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); 

foreach($items as $item) {

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());


echo '"identifier":"'.$product->getSku().'",';
echo '"amount":"'.$product->getPrice().'",';
```

Still, it shows the configurable products instead of the simple one (which are actually ordered). Thus, how can I get ONLY simple products?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this;

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($orderId, 'increment_id');
$items = $order->getAllItems(); 

foreach($items as $item) {

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
  if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ) {

   echo '"identifier":"'.$product->getSku().'",';
   echo '"amount":"'.$product->getPrice().'",';

  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't echo anything :(

Comment: GOT IT! need to use $order->getAllItems(); instead of $order->getAllVisibleItems(); to load all items first

Comment: great, glad it helped. and sorry wasnt paying attention to that bit you said you were getting the product data